# How to export a huge data from a database to a file using mule?

Tags: mule

I have a http endpoint, on request into this endpoint, i need to create a huge database (more than million records) dump and generate a single xml file. I am planning to write a component which will query with pagination and then write it into file? I am new to mule. Can i stream the data from the component into a file connector. If yes how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

A Http endpoint will stream by default unless its an anonymous post. You can do both operations if you use an All processor. For the XML you can use data mapper (with streaming enabled) and for the JDBC you can just send the payload to the JDBC outbound and it will do batched inserting if the payload is of type list

Answer (score 0):

Generally for huge set of Data and bulk operation there is Batch module in Mule.
It process messages in batches and extremely useful in handling large set of data or db operations in bulk. You can consider using batch job
ref :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Batch+Processing